# Save water in Thailand

Tags: definite-article

Because of the recent drought in Thailand, a tv station has launched a campaign to persuade people to use water wisely. The title of this well-meaning effort is "Save The Water".
My question is about the use of the definite article, 'The', in the title. Grammatically speaking, do we need the article? In other words, what is the difference between 'Save The Water' and 'Save Water'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the article is not necessary, but not necessarily misused. The key difference, is that "water" (with no article) speaks about water in general, whereas "the water" implies some more specific area/type of water. In the case that you explain, I would imagine the Thai authorities are using "the" to mean "Thai water" - that is, all the water that is normally used across Thailand, which is dwindling in its supply.

If you were to ask me my opinion, I would say that I prefer no article in this case: Save water!

Answer (score 3):

The phrasing "save the [X]" is commonly used to refer to an endanged species ("save the whales") or a natural land feature ("save the Ballona wetlands").  So using the definite article makes it seem as if  "water" is an endangered species facing *extinction*. So the message is not only to cut down on individual usage (saving on water) but to participate in preserving the nation's supply of water  to "save" it from (rescue from, or protect against) extinction.

This makes sense as a public service message.  I'm not sure if the people who made the ad appreciate this subtle *double entendre*, but it works well.  "Save water" has no such patriotic connotation. Save water" could even be construed as "save up" (some) water in a barrel or tub (because you might not get any tomorrow"), which is the opposite of what the campaign wants to encourage.

See the various meanings of "save":

http://i.word.com/idictionary/save